# Apache Spark arrays fuzzy comparison

Tags: arrays, apache-spark

I have the following DataFrame:

```
function_name |   result_list
--------------------------------
     f1       |  [1,0,0,0,1,0]
     f2       |  [0,0,1,0,1,1]
     f3       |  [1,1,1,0,0,0]
     f4       |  [1,0,0,0,1,0]
```

every array in `result_list` column always have the same length.
In order to find 100% similar arrays - I can simply group them by `result_list` column.

But I also need to find almost similar arrays, let's say arrays that are equal by 95% or 90% or so.
Is there in Apache Spark possibility to achieve it? If so, could you please show an example.

Comment: scala or python ?

Comment: It doesn't matter to me, but python preferable

Comment: interessting question indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`levenshtein-distance` could be a suitable measure for similarity:

```
val df : DataFrame = Seq(
  ("f1",Seq(1,0,0,0,1,0)),
  ("f2",Seq(0,0,1,0,1,1)),
  ("f3",Seq(1,1,1,0,0,0)),
  ("f4",Seq(1,1,0,0,1,0)) // very similar to f1
).toDF("function_name","result_list")


df.alias("a").join(
  df.alias("b"),
    $"a.function_name" =!= $"b.function_name"
)
.withColumn("distance",levenshtein($"a.result_list".cast("string"),$"b.result_list".cast("string")))
  .where($"distance"<=1) // similarity threshold
  // avoid duplication
  .select(sort_array(array($"a.function_name",$"b.function_name")).as("pairing"),$"distance")
  .dropDuplicates("pairing")
  .show()
```

gives :

```
+--------+--------+
| pairing|distance|
+--------+--------+
|[f1, f4]|       1|
+--------+--------+
```

You could also use `levenshtein` in the join condition, but then you loose the information about the distance:

```
df.alias("a").join(
  df.alias("b"),
    $"a.function_name" =!= $"b.function_name" and levenshtein($"a.result_list".cast("string"),$"b.result_list".cast("string")) <= 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful!